# How do I detect if an email client is configured on an Android device?

Tags: android, email, email-client

How do I detect if an email client is configured on an Android device?  If no email account is configured Android treats it as text message (I use android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND). I want to prompt the user that no email client is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of prompting the user that no email client is configured, consider wrapping the ACTION_SEND intent in a chooser via [createChooser()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29). `createChooser()` will return the intent that the user picked.  If the user did not pick a valid email client, you can perhaps pop up an error message or provide the user with the settings screen to declare a valid email client.

Note that it is not possible to determine whether a sending application is a valid "email" application, just whether it is an application for sending.  This is why the chooser should be used, so that the user will be the one to realize that they do not have an email client set up.  Also note that it is extremely rare for a user to have no email client, as they must at least register with their google account when they start their phone (giving them access to gmail).

Here's an example for sending an email with a chooser:

```
sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {"myuser@gmail.com"});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of email message");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));
```

Comment: "Also note that it is extremely rare for a user to have no email client, as they must at least register with their google account when they start their phone (giving them access to gmail)." That's not true. I sell an app to local businesses for internal use, and I offer to pre-install it (for a price) on a new or used Android phone. I've just installed my app on 10 brand-new Samsung Galaxy Xcover 3 phones, and after checking with the customer it was decided to not create any Google account for the phones.