# how to know if the email client of Android has been setup or not?

Tags: android, email

I want to know, if its possible to check and see if the android email client has been setup or not? Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888690/how-do-i-detect-if-an-email-client-is-configured-on-an-android-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't actually want to send an email, and instead want to simply check. But if you are after the first one, then you can try this example:

http://snipplr.com/view/15639/

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code available in the link mentioned by Sky, but it did not work for me. I implemented it as below.

```
public boolean isEmailSetup() {
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(HomeScreen.this);
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
        return accounts.length > 0;
    }
```

You need to specify the permisson `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>` in you AndroidMenifest.xml